# Calculating year since epoch and hours into current year

Tags: c++

I'm trying to calculate the current year and hours into the current year from epoch (Jan 1, 1601). I can get the year correctly, but the hours into the year are wrong. Is my math wrong or is it something to do with overflow?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

uint64_t DaysInYear = 365;
uint64_t HundredNSInHour = 36000000000;
uint64_t HundredNSInDay = 864000000000;
uint64_t HundredNSInYear = 3.1536E14;

int main()
{
    uint64_t offset = 132327645834474780; // 100s of nanoseconds since epoch

    uint64_t year = (offset / HundredNSInYear) + 1601;

    uint64_t hoursIntoYear = (offset % HundredNSInYear) / HundredNSInHour;

    cout << "Year: " << year << "\n" << "HoursIntoYear: " << hoursIntoYear << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `uint64_t HundredNSInYear = 3.1536E14;` is flawed.  `3.1536E14` is a `double` and will lose precision when converted to a `uint64_t`.

Comment: And, of course, there are leap years...

Comment: And also leap seconds, too...

Comment: `HundredNSInYear` would be `HundredNSInDay * DaysInYear`, which is `315360000000000` not `3.1536E14`. You should define the variables in terms of each other for easier management, eg: `uint64_t DaysInYear = 365; uint64_t HoursInDay = 24; uint64_t MinutesInHour = 60;
uint64_t SecondsInMinute = 60; uint64_t HundredNSInSecond = 10000000; uint64_t HundredNSInMinute = HundredNSInSecond * SecondsInMinute; uint64_t HundredNSInHour = HundredNSInMinute * MinutesInHour; uint64_t HundredNSInDay = HundredNSInHour * HoursInDay; uint64_t HundredNSInYear = HundredNSInDay * DaysInYear;`

Comment: And of course, the variables should be declared as `const`